# "Dead Store" Warning in Xcode 

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, nsstring

I am getting a dead store warning when I analyze my project but the project does not crash.
Here is what I am doing

```
NSString *graphUrl = nil;

if ([graphArray count] == 1)
{
    objTrial = [graphArray objectAtIndex:0];

    graphUrl = @"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=s:nda&chf=bg,s,FFFFFF&chs=";

    graphUrl = [graphUrl stringByAppendingString:@"&chd=t:"];
    graphUrl = [graphUrl stringByAppendingString:objTrial.highValue];// get the dead store error here

}
else
{
    //someother operation is done and a value is loaded to aURL
}
```

I get a dead store warning as mentioned in the code.. How can I prevent this?

It would be great if someone could help me out in this

Comment: Presumably you mean `NSString *aUrl = @"";` on that first line?

Comment: if assigning a value to a local variable, but the value is not read by any subsequent instruction, then it is referred to as a Dead Store. Dead Stores are wasteful of processor time and memory. So just use the variable and the warning will go away.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The warning is telling you that the store that you do in the first line gets thrown away (i.e assigning an empty string to the variable and then reassigning it afterwards without using the original value). Just change the first line to the following and the warning should go away:

```
NSString *aUrl;
```

Edit:

you should change the line where you use it also:

```
aURL = [aValue copy];
```

Comment: I tried the same thing you had also suggested, but it gives me the same warning again...

Comment: I assume you are actually doing something with the graphurl variable after the code that you posted? If not, that is the problem

Comment: DOH!!! I am a fool.. did not look at it properly.. I was doing something with graphURL.. I had to assign it to something which I forgot.. thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

"dead store" means something that's not used, or rather something useless.

You get it when you have a variable defined that you never do anything with. So, the Analyzer tells you that you have wasted some storage.

Here you haven't used the aUrl object after assigning it.

It won't cause any problems other than a few bytes of wasted memory. Of course if it's a large object that could be more.

Perhaps someone could chip in with knowledge of compilers, as compiler optimization might take care of dead stores in any case.

Answer (score 2):

*Dead Store* is a value that is assigned but never used. There is nothing to worry about it. But if you can't control yourself from worrying ;-) you can change your code to,

```
NSString aUrl = nil;

if ([anArray count] == 1) {

    // a value is store in aValue
    // then that value is appended to aURL
    aURL = [aURL stringByAppendingString:aValue];

} else {

    aUrl = @"";
    //someother operation is done and a value is loaded to aURL
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I did the same thing but it still gives me that error in the same line. and when I added the aURL = @"";  it gives me the "Value stored at aURL is never read warning" at that line too.. any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I saw your code. Your code is completely alright. It shows the warning because, as I've already said, you are repeatedly assigning values to `graphUrl` without using the previous values. Nothing to worry about the warning. Go ahead with your code.